# Submiting a form using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to submit a form using **PHP**. I am trying to grab the value from two file inputs in my form, yet when I try to index them with my **PHP** code, I keep getting an error.

The **error** I get:

```
Undefined index: profile-pic in C:\xampp\htdocs\shareitme\form-test.php on line 5

Undefined index: cover-pic in C:\xampp\htdocs\shareitme\form-test.php on line 6
```

My **Code**:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $profile_pic= time() . $_FILES['profile-pic']['name'];
    $cover_pic= time() . $_FILES['cover-pic']['name'];

}

?>

    <form id="editprofile" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']     
?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000"/>
        <input type="file" name="profile-pic"/>
        <input type="file" name="cover-pic"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

I know I have the **names** right, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose $_POST is empty, so your 2 variables will never be declared because the if-condition is false. The code inside will never run, so your variables are undefined.

Comment: Only after submit is hit does the php code run

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uploading a file include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form, like below:

```
<form id="editprofile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']     
?>">
```

The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

For more info on forms : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

For renaming a uploaded file, it better to upload it to server with [move_uploaded_file](http://pk1.php.net/move_uploaded_file) and than rename it.

Comment: This answer would be better if it didn't include [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['go']) && $_REQUEST['go'] == "1") {

$profile_pic= time() . $_FILES['profile-pic']['name'];
$cover_pic= time() . $_FILES['cover-pic']['name'];

}

?>

<form id="editprofile" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000"/>
    <input type="file" name="profile-pic"/>
    <input type="file" name="cover-pic"/>
    <input type=hidden name="go" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag.
Whenever you want to post binary datas you must have to set this `enctype` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

1) if you are using file type then your form attribute should be `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

```
<form id="editprofile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

2) Before using your post value it is best practice to check whether its setted or not.

```
$pic=isset($_FILES['profile-pic']['name']) ? $_FILES['profile-pic']['name'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are want to upload file. you need to add `enctype` in from.

```
`enctype="multipart/form-data"'
```

This should work

```
<form id="editprofile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']     
?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here, if I'm not mistaken, is upload images on your server, right? You can simply use a third-party upload tool for that. I'd recommend AjaxUpload as it is based on AJAX and pretty easy to implement. 
For simplicity, I'm applying the upload functionality on one image. You can simply put it inside a function and reuse it.

```
 <p id="showMsg"></p>
 <input type="file" name="profile-pic" id="profilePic" />
```

JQuery:

```
$("#profilePic").ajaxUpload({
url : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 
name: "file",
onSubmit: function() {
    $('#showMsg').html('Uploading ... ');
},
onComplete: function(result) {
    $('#showMsg').html('File uploaded with result' + result);
}
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES)) 
{

    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'upload_dir/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); // This function will upload the image to 'upload_dir' folder. You can modify it as per your requirements.

}

?>
```